# Как сформировать объект в store Ember.js из JSON со стороны бэкенда?

Tags: json, spring, rest, ember.js

Есть rest контроллер на стороне Spring, который отдает по GET запросу JSON ответ. JSON сложный (содержит вложенные объекты).

На стороне фронтенда Ember.js, который должен принять JSON ответ и сформировать объект в store.
Структура моделей в ember полностью повторяет структуру json из spring, включая связи.

В итоге на стороне ember не формируются вложенные объекты, а лишь простые поля.

```
createObject() {
  var _this = this;
  $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/object/getCard?id=24').then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    _this.store.createRecord('cards/object/card', response);
  });
}
```

Пример JSON:

```
{
    "id":24,
    "fullName":"qwerty",
    "form":"zzzzzzzzzzzz",
    "leader":
                {
                    "id":23,
                    "fullName":"testName test",
                    "email":"emailTest"
                }
}
```

Модель leader не заполняется.

Как правильно маппить сложные объекты в Ember.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день.
Может быть и можно вашим способом отправлять запрос на сервер, но мне думается так не делают.

Вы должны отправить запрос на сервер через store.

У вас должна быть готова модель в ember, как [здесь](http://emjs.ru/v2/models/defining-models/) пишут.
У вас есть route в котором происходит запрос к серверу https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/

Например:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findRecord('leader', 23);
  }
});
```

И с сервера, что самое главное, у вас должен прийти ответ в "стиле" json-api. Только в этом случае ответ распарсится как надо, и попадет в store.

https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html

https://jsonapi.org/format/

Если ваш ответ не соответствует этому формату, то необходимо реализовать свой адаптер и сериализатор.